# Service not found for influx/blockchain-influxdb-local" in Traefik 1.7 logs

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I have a K8s cluster with traefik 1.7

In Traefik logs, I get:

```sh
Service not found for influx/blockchain-influxdb-local" 2020-07-24T21:18:26.8761657Z time="2020-07-24T21:18:26Z" level=error msg="Service not found for influx/influxdb-local
```

It may be due to sometimes where I deployed local services to production.

But I can't find any services call influxdb-local. In fact, searching for everything, I can't find any -local one.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it configured in your Ingress❓

```sh
kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces -o=yaml | grep influx
```

Is it configured somewhere in one of the ConfigMaps or other resources❓

```sh
kubectl get cm --all-namespaces -o=yaml | grep influx
kubectl get deploy --all-namespaces -o=yaml | grep influx
kubectl get ds --all-namespaces -o=yaml | grep influx
kubectl get sts --all-namespaces -o=yaml | grep influx
```

✌️☮️